# how to rotate the 3D shape around a fixed point in wpf?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, rotation

I'm trying to rotate my 3-d object in wpf. 
I have tried RotateTransform3D and AxisAngleRotation3D which rotate a shape around axes. I want the 3D shape (or my camera) to rotate three hundred and sixty degrees around a "center point". How Can I do this?